# SageMaker linear-learner results not exact?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker

I have issues with the results i get from the AWS (SageMaker) linear-learner.

Namely I was trying to replicate the results I got from R, SAS or Knime (using linear regression) but unfortunately what I get from the linear-learner is different from the mentioned 3 other ways of calculating it.

I tried different hyperparameters and configurations but I get inexact regression results even in the very trivial case of synthetically generated data satisfying the relationship

Y=X1+2*X2+3

In this case there are exact regression coefficients equal to 1,2 and intercept 3. Unlike the mentioned other software the SageMaker linear-learner is returning me values not even close to the right values
E.g. in one example run I get [0.91547656 1.9826275 3.023757] which is simply not satisfactory.
You can see here the relevant part of my code!

```
study=((1.0,3.0,10.0),(2.0,3.0,11.0),(3.0,2.0,10.0),(4.0,7.0,21.0),(5.0,4.0,16.0))
a = np.array(study).astype('float32')
other_columns=a[:,[0,1]]
labels = a[:,2]
buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, other_columns, labels)
buf.seek(0)
key = 'my-training-data'
boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train', key)).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_train_data = 's3://{}/{}/train/{}'.format(bucket, prefix, key)
output_location = 's3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix)

container = get_image_uri(boto3.Session().region_name, 'linear-learner')

import boto3
sess = sagemaker.Session()
linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(container,
                                       role, 
                                       train_instance_count=1, 
                                       train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',                                       
                                       output_path=output_location,
                                       sagemaker_session=sess)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=2,
                           predictor_type='regressor',
                           loss='squared_loss',
                           epochs=50,
                           early_stopping_patience=100,
                           mini_batch_size=4)
linear.fit({'train': s3_train_data})
```

Do you have some explanation for the observed not exact results?

Thanks
Nikolas

Answer (score 4):

Two possible reasons you aren't getting exact results are stochastic gradient descent (SGD) and regularization, both of which are used in Linear Learner. SGD and regularization are the right thing to do for many real-world machine learning problems, but they lead to inexact results in this toy example.

SGD is an optimization technique which, among other benefits, scales well with large datasets. It scales well as the number of examples and the dimension increase. SGD is poorly suited to very small problems. With extremely large datasets, SGD is the only effective solution. With large, medium, and small datasets, SGD in Linear Learner performs as well as other solvers because of the optimizations built in to the algorithm, such as parallel exploration of multiple settings of the learning rate and other hyperparameters. But for this example dataset, which has zero noise (the relationship between features and label is deterministic) and only 5 examples, a more exact and less scalable solver will do better.

Regularization is applied by default in Linear Learner. To turn it off, set `'wd'=0.0` and `'l1'=0.0`. The algorithm explores multiple values of regularization, including no regularization, and selects the model with the best accuracy on the validation set, or if there is no validation set, the best accuracy on the training data. But due to the very small amount of data available to learn from in this case, that selection is essentially random. So it's likely that the final model used regularization. Regularization pushes model weights, but not the bias, towards zero, so that might explain the parameter estimates mentioned in the post:  [0.91547656 1.9826275 3.023757] instead of [1.0 2.0 3.0]. The two weights were pushed towards zero, and the bias is slightly high in order to compensate.

Regularization is extremely useful in most real-world applications. Training a model with some amount of regularization is almost always the best way to reduce generalization error, aka out of sample error. Using regularization is the right thing to do for real-world datasets, but it will give an inexact solution in this dataset where there is no noise and the assumption of a linear model is exactly correct.

For an exact solution to a linear regression problem on a small dataset, use a solver such as QR decomposition. Examples are SKLearn's `LinearRegression` class, or the `lm` function in R. But keep in mind that these methods will have trouble scaling to larger datasets. And perhaps more importantly, we should turn off regularization for an exact in-sample solution, but the exact solution will usually have worse performance on unseen data compared to the solution with regularization.

SKLearn has several optimizers implemented, including SGD. Here is an example of applying the SGD solver in SKLearn to your example data. Regularization is also turned on by default in SKLearn. The solution is inexact for the reasons described above.

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> import numpy as np
>>> study=((1.0,3.0,10.0),(2.0,3.0,11.0),(3.0,2.0,10.0),(4.0,7.0,21.0),(5.0,4.0,16.0))
>>> a = np.array(study).astype('float32')
>>> other_columns=a[:,[0,1]]
>>> labels = a[:,2]
>>> reg = linear_model.SGDRegressor(max_iter=50)
>>> reg.fit(other_columns, labels)
SGDRegressor(alpha=0.0001, average=False, epsilon=0.1, eta0=0.01,
       fit_intercept=True, l1_ratio=0.15, learning_rate='invscaling',
       loss='squared_loss', max_iter=50, n_iter=None, penalty='l2',
       power_t=0.25, random_state=None, shuffle=True, tol=None, verbose=0,
       warm_start=False)
>>> reg.coef_
array([1.39560259, 2.17536485])
>>> reg.intercept_
array([0.77972575])
```